Does EndpointMetadata include inherited attributes?
In aspnet core there are few ways the access the attributes of an endpoint. Prior to Core a check could be made if a certain attribute is applied to an endpoint as follows:
actionExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true).Length != 0

Similarly in core you can do something like:
((ControllerActionDescriptor)actionExecutingContect.ActionDescriptor).MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), inherit: true).Length != 0

However, I have read using GetCustomAttributes is slow with most places recommending using EndpointMetadata (despite Microsoft explicitly saying "This API is meant for infrastructure and should not be used by application code.") or getting the endpoint from the HttpContext and accessing Metadata directly from there:
actionExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<MyAttribute>().Count() != 0

or
HttpContext.GetEndpoint().Metadata.OfType<MyAttribute>().Count() != 0

However it is not clear if EndpointMetadata or Metadata include attributes that are inherited, or if it is possible to filter on inheritance as can be done with GetCustomAttributes.
Is it possible to include or exclude inherited attributes with EndpointMetadata or Metadata?

By default, EndpointMetadata and HttpContext.GetEndpoint().Metadata in ASP.NET Core do not automatically include inherited attributes. The inclusion of inherited attributes relies on how the attributes are discovered and associated with the endpoint during the application's startup and routing configuration. To include inherited attributes, you would need a custom implementation that uses reflection to identify these attributes and manually add them to the endpoint's metadata. This approach allows for the inclusion of inherited attributes but requires additional setup and configuration.

Thank you @JalpaPanchal . If you link documentation on inheritance handling and turn this into an answer I will accept it. It would be even better if you can add an example of safely updating EndpointMetadata. Though I suspect that's not safe since it's intended for infrastructure and not application code.

there is no direct, detailed official documentation specifically addressing the handling of inherited attributes through EndpointMetadata or demonstrating how to safely update EndpointMetadata for the purpose of including inherited attributes. you are right its not recommended and straightforward

For documentation I was referring to anything showing EndpointMetadata does not include inherited attributes. Even source code would be sufficient. It seems like if I want something static like EndpointMetadata that includes inherited attributes I'd want to roll my own for safety and to distinguish between attributes that are inherited or not.

I have posted sample code that might can help you

By default, EndpointMetadata and HttpContext.GetEndpoint().Metadata in ASP.NET Core do not automatically include inherited attributes. The inclusion of inherited attributes relies on how the attributes are discovered and associated with the endpoint during the application's startup and routing configuration. To include inherited attributes, you would need a custom implementation that uses reflection to identify these attributes and manually add them to the endpoint's metadata. This approach allows for the inclusion of inherited attributes but requires additional setup and configuration.
Below is the sample code regarding handling inherited attributes:
Use Reflection to Identify Inherited Attributes:
var attributes = typeof(MyController).GetMethod("MyAction").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), inherit: true);

Directly manipulating EndpointMetadata is not a standard practice and isn't directly supported, you can use this information to conditionally apply logic within your application, rather than trying to modify the metadata collection. For instance, you could use this reflection-based approach within middleware or an action filter to apply certain behaviors if an inherited attribute is present.
public class MyAttribute : Attribute { }

public class MyAttributeActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var methodInfo = ((ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionDescriptor).MethodInfo;
        var hasAttribute = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true).Any();
        
        if (hasAttribute)
        {
            // custom code 
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }
}


Thank you. My understanding is EndpointMetadata is calculated once at startup time, whereas this we re-calculate attributes every call. So it will be slower, but get the job done.

@RobMosher  GetCustomAttributes allows checking inherited attributes via reflection but is slow. EndpointMetadata and HttpContext metadata provide faster access but don't inherently support inherited attributes. Using reflection within an action filter offers a flexible solution for handling inheritance at the cost of performance.For scenarios heavily reliant on inherited attributes, this compromise is necessary for correctness, though caching reflection results could mitigate performance drawbacks.
